# How do I know, when my thread is ended?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I'm developing a game and I'm using multiple Threads for my loading screen, to load the music and the textures.

I start the threads this way:

```
backgroundgeluidThread = new Thread(loadmusic);
backgroundtexturesThread = new Thread(loadtextures);

backgroundgeluidThread.Start();
backgroundtexturesThread.Start();
```

After that, I use an `Thread.Sleep(8000)`, because I don't know when the threads stopped and are finished with their jobs. I can see it in the output of my IDE, but I don't know when my threads are finished.

Thanks in Advance, and ask me if you don't understand my question.

Comment: Why are you loading in a different thread if you're still going to wait for them to finish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to wait for an Thread to finish call it's `Join()` method:

```
backgroundgeluidThread.Join(); 
backgroundtexturesThread.Join();
```

It will return directly when the thread has finished.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx

Comment: I immediatly tried your solution to this problem, and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx

Use Thread.Join to block until the threads finish, as you have 2 threads and need to wait for both, you can just "Join" them one after the other:

```
firstThread.Join();
secondThread.Join();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) to make the calling code wait until the specified thread has finished execution.